# Azure - relation between resource group and affinity group

Tags: azure, azure-affinity-group

I have read about affinity group, and it allocates the services close in the datacenter, same rack. On the other hand, the new resource groups give me easy access for managing my services related.

I want to deploy an App with a website + sql + storage, so im going to create a resource group for them, and for better performance, i also want to choose an affinity group (previously created), but i cant.

Using the portal management i can choose a affinity group but not a affinity group. And using the beta portal management i can choose a resource group but not an affinity group (affinity group no appears on Location list).

I tried using the powershell mode for managing resource groups, but the cmdlet for create a website dont have a parameter for affinity group (only have a Location).

I was wondering if in one deployment i can choose an affinity group and resource group. There is no docs for this. Or maybe resource group is a replacement for affinity groups, i dont know.

Edit: I still cant do it
PD: hahah sorry about my gramatical errors, we speak spanish here in Peru.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can create a Resource Group that belongs to an affinity group:

1. From the old portal, create an affinity group (if not already
   created)
2. From the old portal, create a cloud service and associate it with
   the affinity group.
3. From the new portal, the cloud service is now listed under "Resource
   Groups"
4. Now when you add a service to the Resource Group it will also be associated with the cloud service and the affinity group.

It seems like 'Cloud Services' are now called 'Resource Groups' but I can't find any documentation to confirm this.

Answer (score 0):

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-migrate-to-regional-vnet/
Seems that it's less important now than before to have affinity groups.